# Counting query results and displaying them in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, aggregate

I'm trying to count the number of each asset for an account and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm getting this error "Content cannot be displayed: Invalid field quantity for AggregateResult". Any ideas?

**Controller Class**

```
public class assetSummary {
    public account acc;

    public String name {get;set;}
    public integer quantity {get;set;}

    public assetSummary(string n,integer q){
        this.quantity=q;
        this.name=n;
    }
    public assetSummary(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.acc = (Account)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public List<assetSummary> assetList = new List<assetSummary>();

    public list<assetSummary> getListOut(){
        AggregateResult[] ar = [SELECT Item__r.name name, count(id) FROM Serial_Tracker__c WHERE Account__c = :acc.ID GROUP BY Item__r.name];
        for (AggregateResult resultList : ar){
            assetList.add(new assetSummary(String.valueOf(resultList.get('name')),integer.valueOf(resultList.get('quantity'))));
        }
        return assetList;
    }
}
```

**VF page**`

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="assetSummary">   
<apex:pageblock title="Asset Summary">
    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!ListOut}" var="lo">
        <apex:column value="{!lo['name']}" headervalue="Name" >
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!lo['quantity']}" headervalue="quantity">
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageblock>          
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to create separate classes for things like controllers and data holders so something like this:

```
public class AssetSummaryController {

    // This inner class just holds the data needed for the page
    public class AssetSummary {

        public String name {get;set;}
        public integer quantity {get;set;}

        public AssetSummary(string name, integer quantity) {
            this.name = name;
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }
    }

    private account acc;

    public AssetSummaryController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.acc = (Account)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public list<AssetSummary> getListOut() {
        list<AssetSummary> assetList = new list<AssetSummary>();
        AggregateResult[] ar = [
                SELECT Item__r.name name, count(id) quantity
                FROM Serial_Tracker__c
                WHERE Account__c = :acc.ID
                GROUP BY Item__r.name
                ];
        for (AggregateResult resultList : ar){
            assetList.add(new AssetSummary(
                    String.valueOf(resultList.get('name')),
                    Integer.valueOf(resultList.get('quantity'))
                    ));
        }
        return assetList;
    }
}
```

which then allows the page to look like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AssetSummaryController">   
<apex:pageblock title="Asset Summary">
    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!ListOut}" var="lo">
        <apex:column value="{!lo.name}" headervalue="Name" >
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!lo.quantity}" headervalue="Quantity">
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:pageblock>          
</apex:page>
```

The error you were seeing was that you had not provided the alias name "quantity" in the aggregate query. I strongly suggest formatting queries on multiple lines so it is easier to spot such omissions.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it. Also thanks for the tips will take them on board :)