# How to get a grouping count in a SOQL query?

Tags: soql

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get a count of the number of kids per location.

Here is the current query that works and populates my VF page.

```
SELECT puLocation__r.Name LocationName, 
                    puLocation__r.notes__c LocationNotes,
                    puLocation__r.Milk_Location__c MilkLocation,
                    puLocation__r.Location_type__c LocationType
             FROM Child_Consent_Form__c 
             GROUP BY puLocation__r.Name, 
                      puLocation__r.notes__c,
                      puLocation__r.Milk_Location__c,
                      puLocation__r.Location_type__c];
```

This query below worked in the query editor but the forum helped me figure out that this wasn't going to work on my VisualForce page because of the `count()`. The `count(Name)` gave me the total number of kids per location.

```
//Records = [SELECT puLocation__r.Name, puLocation__r.Milk_Location__c, puLocation__r.notes__c, COUNT(Name) from Child_Consent_Form__c GROUP BY puLocation__r.Name, puLocation__r.Milk_Location__c, puLocation__r.notes__c ];
```

Here is the original thread.

[Unknown property 'SObject. - Why can't I display the object?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/202953/unknown-property-sobject-why-cant-i-display-the-object/202955?noredirect=1#comment306445_202955)

My problem is that I can't figure out how to get around this.

Comment: This is part of why people are encouraged to wait for a decent amount of time before accepting an answer. On your first question, David Reed's comment on his answer nails it. To quote (or as best I can do here in the comments): **Generally speaking, you can do `SELECT Name, (SELECT Id FROM Child_Objects__r) FROM Parent_Object__c WHERE...`, and then in Visualforce obtain the count with `{! parent_object.Child_Objects__r.size }`**

Comment: Check this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84256/counting-query-results-and-displaying-them-in-visualforce

Comment: You should really take at least a few minutes to **[Read The Manual](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm)**. Salesforce has thorough and clear documentation about its query syntax. That includes how **[Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm)** work. Neglecting to research well documented features very often leads to down-votes, as you have seen here.

Comment: Hi Adrian - Thank you for pointing that out. I thought that I was being smart and opening another thread. The goal was to get Derek more click points. My bad. At some point, I hope to support the community. Right now I am trying to understand why this isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very clearly answered in the documentation on **[Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm)**:

> #### COUNT() and COUNT(fieldName)
>
> Returns the number of rows matching the query criteria. For example using `COUNT()`:
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT()
> FROM Account
> WHERE Name LIKE 'a%'
> ```
>
> For example using `COUNT(fieldName)`:
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(Id)
> FROM Account
> WHERE Name LIKE 'a%'
> ```
>
> The `COUNT(fieldName)` syntax is available in API version 18.0 and later. If you are using a `GROUP BY` clause, use `COUNT(fieldName)` instead of `COUNT()`. For more information, see [COUNT() and COUNT(fieldName)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm).

Note that last paragraph. Specifically:

> ***If you are using a GROUP BY clause, use COUNT(fieldName) instead of COUNT().***

That means you would add `COUNT(Id)` as your field, and optionally include an alias:

```
SELECT Parent__r.Name parentName, COUNT(Id) childCount
FROM MyObject__c GROUP BY Parent__r.Name
```